# Why inserting varchar2 for number works in Oracle database?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I don't understand how can we insert a `varchar2` data into a column with a datatype of `number`.

Consider following sequence of queries:

```
create table aniket.test(id number);

insert into aniket.test(id) 
values ('1');

select * from aniket.test;
```

It works fine though I am using quotes. How does it work? Is `varchar2` internally converted to number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Oracle supports implicit data conversion: [Data Conversion (12.1 documentation)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17209/sql_elements002.htm#SQLRF00214)

Answer (score 1):

It is based on your nls parameters. For example:

```
SQL> show parameter NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
nls_numeric_characters               string      ,
SQL> ALTER SESSION SET NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS= ",."
  2  /

Session altered.

SQL> create table ttt(
  2    id number
  3  );

Table created.

SQL> insert into ttt values('57,4');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into ttt values('27.93');
insert into ttt values('27.93')
                       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01722: invalid number
```

As you can see oracle can't implicitly convert the input, the input has to be a number. So let's adjust our nls parameter:

```
SQL> ALTER SESSION SET NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS= ".,"
  2  /

Session altered.

SQL> insert into ttt values('27.93');

1 row created.

SQL> select id from ttt;

        ID
----------
      57.4
     27.93
```

That was a brief introduction into oracle implicit conversion. For more details you can check [this blog](http://diefororacle.blogspot.ru/2014/07/nls-environment-and-implicit-type.html) and [oracle documentations](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A84870_01/doc/server.816/a76966/ch2.htm)